# Bootstrap и его табы: переход на страницу

Tags: html, bootstrap

Друзья, как сделать, что если переходишь с другой страницы на новую страницу (а на ней табы) и что бы автоматом открылся определенный таб ?

Comment: Нужно запоминать последнюю открытую таб.

Comment: как ее запомниать если мы там еще ниразу небыли ? например там 7 табов и я точно знаю надо перейти и открыть 4ый, как ? может надо передать какой то параметр ?

Comment: Посмотрите ответы @Шрек,@Кал1ша. Если первый раз открываем страницу тогда берем значение по умолчанию. 

А дальше просто запоминаем последний таб(записываете в куки или сессий).Табы у вас на чем? 

На [бутстрапе][1] ? Или jQueri UI?


  [1]: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.div_tab').eq(n).click();
```

где n - номер табы.

Answer (score 0):

нормальный способ, который описан в [документации](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs):

```
$('#myTab li:eq(2) a').tab('show'); // Select third tab (0-indexed)
```

способ, которым пользовался я, т.к. по уже забытым причинам первый способ не срабатывал:

```
$('#myTab').find('li').removeClass('active').eq(3).addClass('active');
$('#myTabContent').find('.tab-pane').removeClass('active in').eq(3).addClass('active in');
```

3 в `.eq(3)` - номер четвёртого таба

Answer (score -1):

По умолчанию 4тому табу присвоить значение открытого и все.