# Таб из bootstrap: ссылка на содержимое второго таба с другой страницы

Tags: bootstrap

Здравствует! На данном сайте я уже описывал свою проблему, но ответа не получил. Наткнулся на пост с [похожей проблемой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/166949/html-bootstrap-%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83), но ее решения я до конца не понял. Собственно вот в чем дело:
Имеется такой таб из bootstrap:

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Первая вкладка</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Вторая вкладка</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
    <p>Содержание первого таба</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
    <p>Содержание второго таба</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как реализовать ссылку на содержимое второго таба с другой страницы?

Comment: @Ponchik т.е чтобы автоматом скроллилась к этой таблице?

Comment: В каждом табе имеется некий контент. К примеру, в втором табе есть изображение некой продукции, щелкая по этому изображению я перехожу на страницу этой продукции. При обратном возврате меня бросает не на тот же таб(второй), а на первый. Можно ли реализовать возврат на необходимый мне таб?

Comment: JS куки или какой-то get параметр в адресной строке

Comment: @Ponchik попробуйте добавить к ссылке http://test.com/#home

Comment: Ссылкой не совсем понял, JS плохо знаю(только начал изучать), если можно, то более подробно объясните.

Answer (score 1):

Там все работает через якори.

```html
<div class="tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#s1" data-toggle="tab">Первая секция</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#s2" data-toggle="tab">Вторая секция</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#s3" data-toggle="tab">Третья секция</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="s1">
            <p>Сейчас вы просматриваете содержимое первой секции.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="s2">
            <p>Сейчас вы просматриваете содержимое второй секции.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="s3">
            <p>Сейчас вы просматриваете содержимое третьей секции.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Обратите внимание на `id="s3"`, `id="s2"` и так далее.
То есть, если к ссылке добавить `#s2`, то будет открыт по умолчанию таб и *id = s2*.