# Переход по табом

Tags: html5, вёрстка, bootstrap

Использую bootstrap tabs мне нужно было сделать табы в табах. 
Сделал так

```html
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs1">
      <li class="active ">ТАБ1</li>
      <li>ТАБ2</li>
      <li>ТАБ3</li>
    </ul>
 <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="panel1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#panel1-1">ТАБ1-1</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#panel1-2">ТАБ1-2</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#panel1-3">ТАБ1-3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
         <div id="panel1-1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
     ИНФА
    </div>
         <div id="panel1-2" class="tab-pane fade">
     ИНФА
    </div>
         <div id="panel1-3" class="tab-pane fade">
    ИНФА 
    </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div id="panel2" class="tab-pane fade">
        ИНФА
   </div>
       <div id="panel3" class="tab-pane fade">
         ИНФА
      </div>
 </div>
```

Как мне теперь перейти в нужный мне таб по ссылке? например нужно с другой страницы отрыть таб panel1-1.
Пробовал [http://урл-сайта/страница#panel1-1](http://%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BB-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0/%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0#panel1-1). Но не работает.

Comment: если страница генерируется на сервере (например php), то можно передать гет-параметр и обработать его. В зависимости от его значения добавлять или нет класс active к табу

Comment: вот еще один способ: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/166980/199966 Правда здесь тоже надо как-то идентифицировать страницу, поэтому все тот же гет-параметр в помощь

Comment: воспользовался этим примером
    $(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');})
Вкладки меняются, но страница до открытой вкладки не пролистывается. Точнее только первая пролистывается, а остальные нет.